# Dialogflow Slack Events

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, slack

Building a chatbot for Slack with Dialoglow and a custom fulfillment.
I want to receive and handle the Slack event when the user opens a dialog with Bot.

Event is **im_created**

I've checked on the custom subscription URL (without Dialoglow) and I'm able to receive this event. But inside Dialoglow I don't get any events.
I suppose the problem is with the naming of events (attached as a link). Did somebody encounter this?

Plus, I don't receive any other events. Request URL inside Slack is valid and correct (verified).

How events inside Dialogflow are named:

[image: How events inside Dialogflow are named]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dialogflow events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events) are completely independant from [Slack API Events](https://api.slack.com/events).  Currently, Dialogflow only supports a [welcome event](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#event_name) from Slack and does not support any events you've mentioned in your question (`im-created`, `im-open`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, looks like it. If anyone has encountered the same issue - I've made an RTM listener, that detects all the necessary events and manually parse them. Doesn't look like a nice solution but it works.

Comment: Nice!  Can you post a link to you code for future StackOverflowers?