# How to handle the answer of a custom payload in dialogflow?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es, chatbot, payload

I have a bot that handles well the welcome intent using Dialogflow for Slack. However I don't know how to deal with the answer to the `welcome intent` to fire the second post. Indeed, the `welcome intent`, which outputs a `await_answer1` context, shows the following template in json:

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*How have you been feeling?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mihailo>"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "divider"
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":tired_face: *I’ve been feeling more exasperated and hopeless*"
            },
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "value": "2",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            },
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":expressionless: *Generally, less freaked out than other people*"
            }
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "3"
            },
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":relieved: *More calm and hopeful*"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "divider"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I would like to handle the answer. So I created an `answer1` intent which takes the `await_answer1` as an input context. The training phrases are the output of the above template : `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`. And the Default text response is `Interesting!` However after selecting the answer is the `Fallback intent` rather than `answer1`. Therefore, how to handle thee answer of a custom payload in dialogflow?

## AngelDev answer

I tried to include `block_id`:

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*How have you been feeling?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mihailo>"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "divider"
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "1"
            },
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "1",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":tired_face: *I’ve been feeling more exasperated and hopeless*"
            }
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "2"
            },
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "2",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":expressionless: *Generally, less freaked out than other people*"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":relieved: *More calm and hopeful*"
            },
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "3"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "4",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":fearful: *More scared and panicked*"
            },
            "accessory": {
              "value": "4",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "5", 
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":open_mouth: *More surprised and baffled*"
            },
            "accessory": {
              "value": "5",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Yet when I click on the button the DialogFlow bot falls on the DefaultFallback intent rather than going to the `answer1` intent that should handle the `await_answer1` context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure why, but if you remove the output and input context, this setup works fine.

[image]

These are the accessory properties I used, I only changed the `value` property and added those values as a example phrase to my intents.

```
"accessory": {
              "value": "First",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            },

"accessory": {
              "value": "Second",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            },

"accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "Third"
```

If you are looking to build a very customized Slack experience it might be worth to investigate into the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/start). OnClick events and other Slack specific events are currenty [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945916/dialogflow-slack-events) from within the Dialogflow UI, but you can integrate it with code in a [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) and from there customize your conversation in greater detail.

Comment: You are right, removing the input and output context fires the second intent. However, I have several follow up templates and I want them to be fired in a specific order. That's why I was using contexts. So if I remove all of the contexts wouldn't it trigger the templates in a random order?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the input context your users will be able to trigger that intent at any time. Some other integrations handle clicks through specific events to prevent this situation, but as far as I know this cannot be done through the UI of Dialogflow for Slack. So you will need to use some code to cover this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You must include a block_id in your custom payload in each element of the block arrangement and this value must be in the training phrases of your intention since when you receive an interaction you receive this block_id. For example

```
  {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "*How have you been feeling?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mihailo>"
        },
       block_id: "section_1"
     }
```

I hope it is what you are looking for but you can write to me to help you solve your doubts.

Comment: Hola! Thanks for your answer and your help! Do you mean that `section_1` should be in the training prases that catches my follow-up intent? I have updated my question with my attempt to reproduce your ideas.

Comment: hello, Dialogflow detects the attribute "value": "1" of your block and sends this in the attribute "queryText": "1." so it should recognize the intent "answer1" but it does not do it because the slack event create another session where the output context "await_answer1"  is not present , so you should delete the context and this will work.

Comment: I suspect it is because two endpoints are used in the integration:
https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/v2/integrations/slack/
and for events
https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/v1/integrations/slack